# IDN domain and Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, fbconnect, idn

Does Facebook Connect support IDN domains with special characters such as æ, ø, å?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem with shares from WordPress to FB. The problem is apparently on the side of Facebook. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/idn-site-posts-not-publicized-and-no-sharing